# Best practices for reducing/clustering data which is location/time based?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction

I have event-based data (or *longitudinal data*) which has a person's age, gender, location (zipcode etc.), the datetime when they saw something, and how long they watched it.

I have a project requirement to reduce the number of dimensions ([PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or [t-SNE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-distributed_stochastic_neighbor_embedding)) and cluster the data ([k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) probably).

However, I'm wondering if clustering becomes meaningless since the data is tied to a location, and changes over time? It's been suggested to aggregate the data using an average of the durations.  I'm not convinced that's a good idea either.

**Can anyone explain the best practices for clustering this type of data?  Or, confirm/deny my suspicions?**

Thanks!

*Disclaimer:  I have a background in Computer Science not Statistics.*

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to cluster based on these attributes. Before clustering, first figure out how to **quantify similarity**. Without a good measure of similarity or distance, neither the projections nor the clusterings will work.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Hmm, you make an interesting point. I do not have experience with this sort of thing. So, I wouldn't know how to go about quantifying similarity. I could compare zipcodes for distance, though that wouldn't take into consideration age, gender, viewing etc...

Comment: I'm not aware of a one-size-fits-all solution. It totally depends on your data and use case.